# Asp.net Mvc Report With Rdlc dataset with Model Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

I am using VisualStudio 2013 and asp.net mvc4.Making Report with rdlc.The question is how can make rdlc dataset to select Model class, I cannot find my project data at datasource.I want to select Viewmodel class within Model Layer.
Any suggestion plz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an Web-Form (.aspx-file) to your MVC project. Afterwards the *Add Dataset* dialog will show all available classes. The class needs at least one method without parameters that returns an IEnumerable (maybe IEnumerable works as well).

This works for my MVC5 project, should be fine for MVC4 too.

Comment: Does this imply that a dataset for a report must be flat, and use grouping for nested list items?  Or is there a way to use an IEnumerable of a class that includes another IEnumerable directly?